# Load a collection view controller inside a view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab View Controller and one of the tabs in it is a view controller. I need to be able to load a collection view controller within that view controller when user taps on an image, using swift.
Can this be done programmatically? I have 3 tabs in my tab view controller and need to do this only for one of them, not all.
What I have done so far:
Added a new swift file. home.swift
Added this to it:

```
class EventsController: UICollectionViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    }
}
```

Then I changed the class of the view controller to EventsController,But It throws the following exception:
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with 
identifier Home from storyboard Main, but didn't get a UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a UICollectionViewController class, which is a subclass of UIViewController. You can do this very easily by doing this:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let homeImage = UIImage(named: "home")
    let mainController = MainCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainController)


    viewControllers = [navigationController]
}
```

Note that *you must specify* a layout for the UICollectionViewController.

Now your UICollectionViewController class:

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow this. As I said, I have already added a new View Controller as the new tab of my tab bar controller. I added a new swift file, home.swift, and inside it I added this class: class EventsController: UICollectionViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        
        
        //collectionView?.registerClass(EventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

Comment: Which part confused you?

Comment: As I said, I have already added a new View Controller as the new tab of my tab bar controller. I added a new swift file, home.swift, and inside it I added this class:   class EventsController: UICollectionViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("!!!!")
    }

}     And then I set this class to be used by that tab. Result is: exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: [UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier Home from storyboard Main, but didn't get a UICollectionView

Comment: I added more details to my questions as well, hope it clarifies what I need to do.